# Manipulating Extension popup's DOM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm new at working on chrome extension and i'm looking for guidance.

At the moment, I'm trying to load data coming from an api call inside a dropdown menu within my extension's popup.

While the data is coming through from the api, I can't access the popup DOM. I hear that I should use sendMessage but I can't find a proper explanation to why and how.

Here is what I have:

popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="search_panel">
            <div class="logos" id="head_b">
                <img src="chrome-extension://hfbigccdfoeegoicoioalffcngoekege/img/tedBtn.png" alt="" class="logo_explicite">
            </div>
            <p id="hep">p</p>
            <div class="form">
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="subject" class="subject_label">Sujets</label>
                    <select name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Sélectionnez un sujet">
                        <option value="" data-keywords="" data-desc="" selected>select subjects</option>
                        <option value="Sujet 1" data-desc="bla blabla bla">subject 1</option>
                        <option value="Sujet 2" data-desc="bla blabla bla">subject 2</option>
                    </select>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function load() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: 'load.js'
  }); 
}

load();
```

load.js

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", "https://url/api/subject/list", false);
    xhr.send();

    var result = xhr.responseText;
    var obj = JSON.parse(result);
    console.log(obj); 

    var select = $('#subject');
    console.log(select); //undefined



    // for(index in obj) {
    //     select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(obj[index], index);
    // }
    console.log(rep);
```

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "-",
"description": "-",
"version": "0.1",
"permissions": [
    "tabs","<all_urls>",
    "https://url/*",
    "http://url/*"
    ],
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "img/*.png",
    "reponses.json"
  ],
"content_scripts": [
    {
    "css": [ "style.css"],
    "matches": [
        "http://twitter.com/*",
        "https://twitter.com/*"
        ],
    "js": ["jquery.min.js", "content.js"]
    }
],


"background" : { "scripts": ["background.js", "popup.js"] },

"manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: You need to Include `load.js` in `popup.html`

Comment: it doesn't change anything. load.js is working fine, data is coming from the api but I want to retrieve the select element to append all the option received from the data call. I can't manage to access the extension's popup dom to make the changes.

Comment: tabs.executeScript runs a **content script** in a tab (in the web page). It's totally not what you want to do because the popup is not related to the web page tab in any way. Like already suggested, instead of executeScript include load.js in popup.html using the standard script tag. Note, since the popup is a totally separate thing, to debug it you need to right-click it, then click inspect.

Comment: omg... it's true. so finally it works perfectly. Can you post and answer about the fact that popup and page are different envs so inspect need to be triggered on this specific part. I will accept it. Thanks